# How to add click source to php file?

Tags: php

I am trying to find out from which pages on my site, my affiliate clicks are coming.

For example lets say my article is here;

> www.mysite.com/article-title/

The article above contains my affiliate link which is located here:

> www.mysite.com/go/affiliate.php

So whenever somebody clicks the above affiliate link in the article, I want to find out the source URL (in this case www.mysite.com/article-title/). I will also add this code to the affiliate.php file.

I tried

```
$_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"];
```

But it doesn't work.

Is there any other way besides using URL variables?

Comment: '*But it doesn't work.*' - What doesn't work?

Comment: The referrer is known as highly unreliable since … well, forever, basically. You might get one, you might not get one, you might get a forged one (for example if privacy-related browser extensions interfere.) _“Is there any other way besides using URL variables?”_ - if both URLs are underneath the same domain, as your example suggests, and controlled by the same system - then session variables might be an option to track which “path” the user takes.

Comment: Why don't you want to use URL variables for this?

Answer (score 0):

You can add a session variable that will save the value of the last viewed page, and then retrieve the information from there. Alternatively, you can add a query parameter to the affiliation link URL which will dynamically change based on the page in which that link was shown. For example: `www.mysite.com/go/affiliate.php?ref=article-title`.

Answer (score -1):

```html
<?php
$c = curl_init('www.mysite.com/go/affiliate.php'); 
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1); 
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_REFERER, 'www.mysite.com/article-title/'); 
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'CURL via PHP'); 
$page = curl_exec($c); 
curl_close($c);
```

Comment: So, what about editing your answer to contain more information?